# How do I assert activity counts in a workflow trace after a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I am unit testing a WF4 service using [the Unit testing Nuget package](https://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview&referringTitle=Home). There is a functionality for asserting that stuff does or does not exist in the end-of-test tracking information.

Consider the following unit test code:

```
WorkflowServiceTestHost host = null;
using (host = CreateHost())
{
    var proxy = new ServiceClient(Binding, ServiceAddress);
// Call receive points in the workflow

}
finally
{
    host.Tracking.Trace();
    // I would like to assert stuff like the WF did not abort
    // For now, I would just like to assert that there are a 
    // certain number of invocations of a specific activity.
    // I can find no examples of how to call this:
    host.Tracking.Assert.ExistsCount(?????what goes here???);
}
```

How does one call `ExistsCount()`?  The prototype looks like this:

```
public void ExistsCount<TRecord>(Predicate<TRecord> predicate, int count, string message = null) where TRecord : TrackingRecord
```

but I can find no examples or documentation to understand what is expected for the `predicate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the easiest way to handle this is not via

```
host.Tracking.Assert.ExistsCount()
```

rather you want to look at the collection

```
host.Tracking.Records
```

and then use LINQ on them to confirm what you think should be there.  For instance if you expected the workflow to call the **ABC** activity class five times you could check it as follows:

```
var trackingRecords = host.Tracking.Records.ToArray();
var myRecords = trackingRecords.OfType<ActivityStateRecord>()
    .Where(
        r =>
            r.Activity != null && r.State == "Executing" &&
            r.Activity.TypeName.EndsWith("ABC")).ToArray();
Assert.AreEqual(5,myRecords.Length);
```